# After installing apex 4.2.6 cant open admin page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I installed apex 4.2.6 by this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/upgrade-apex-for-xe-154969.html, and after finishing all commands and after i start database and get started Xe server or start http://localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin, it doesnt do anything, just blank screen.

ANyone knows what could be the problem

Comment: could be anything. Did you check any logs? What listener and web server do you use? Is it an upgrade or a new install? Are you sure all the steps are followed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total newbie myself, but try this URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p replace localhost with this IP address. I think that will work.